# Need some help to retrieve album cover with Last F.M

Tags: dependencies, last.fm

The dependencies for the [last.fm API](https://github.com/jkovacs/lastfm-java/tree/master) don't work.

I need some help to retrieve album cover with Last FM.

I've this code in Main Activity

```
TextView metaTitle = findViewById(R.id.meta_title);

String[] parts = metaTitle.getText().toString().split("-");

String artist = parts[0].trim();
String title = parts[1].trim();

Track track = Track.getInfo(artist, title, "8a31c329f76d81616598db6780537edf\n");

String imageUrl = track.getImageURL(ImageSize.LARGE);

ImageView cover = findViewById(R.id.cover);
Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(cover);
```

But the dependencies in my gradle file doesn't work:

```
implementation 'de.u-mass:lastfm-java:0.1.2'
```

```
> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find de.u-mass:lastfm-java:0.1.1.
     Required by:
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Anyone know it ?

Comment: Could you please post your complete build.gradle file? Also it looks weird that the error message refers to version `0.1.1` but in your gradle file you have stated `0.1.2`. So could you please also include the complete error stack trace that you get when you build the project. For me, I can build a project that has only `dependencies { implementation 'de.u-mass:lastfm-java:0.1.2' }`